# PHP-HTML embed code

Tags: php, html, forms, drop-down-menu, download

I am designing simple HTML with a drop-down list and a button.

I want to know how to retrieve the selected drop-down item into php variable. I am writing php-html embed code. I am confused about how to get the particular value in php variable. Also, I would like to know how to download a file after selecting that particular item. I already created downloading file, but I have no idea how to invoke those from selected drop-down item.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

I am pasting some php-html code which I am trying:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Get All Reports</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<div>
<form action="">
<table>
<tr><td>
<select onchange="ReportList(this.form,0)">
<option value="SubscriptionReport.php" >Subscription Report
<option value="DownloadHistoryReport.php">DownloadHistory Report
<option value="AppEventReport.php">AppEvent Report

</select>


</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<button name="isSubmit">Download</button>
</td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</center>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but if I wanted to access those fields in this page, then how will I retrieve it? I dont wanted to send those values to some other page, I like process those valuses in same page.

Comment: Then just submit to "this" page. (Refer to my answer, below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of that input will be passed via whatever method you use in your form. The page it is sent to will access the form input value through `$_GET` or `$_POST`, whichever method was used.

```
<form method="post" action="process.php">
    <input type="text" value="3" name="myInput" id="myInputId" />
</form>
```

Would be accessed, in *process.php*, as such:

```
<?php
    $inputValue = $_POST['myInput'];
```

Notice that the input is passed via its `name` and not its `id` attribute.

For a GET form submission:

```
<form method="get" action="process.php">
    <input type="text" value="3" name="myInput" id="myInputId" />
</form>
```

Would be accessed, in *process.php*, as such:

```
<?php
    $inputValue = $_GET['myInput'];
```

Note that when you submit a form via GET, it appends the key/value pair to the querystring:

```
http://www.example.com/process.php?myInput=3
```

If you want to submit your form to the same page on which it exists, just leave the `action` attribute blank.

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" value="3" name="myInput" id="myInputId" />
</form>
```

**NOTE:** PHP can only access form variables *once they have been submitted*. If you want to retrieve the value of a form element, you must use javascript event handlers. PHP is server-side and cannot react to user input until the server receives it. Javascript is client-side. It "sees" what the user does in the browser and can handle those events.

Comment: So, Can I access those values with attribute id, as drop-down list in html dont have attribute name,so this following code will work?               <select >
<option value="SubscriptionReport.php" id="subscription" >Subscription Report
<option value="DownloadHistoryReport.php" id="downloadHistory">DownloadHistory Report
<option value="AppEventReport.php" id="appEvent">AppEvent Report

</select>  $reportList = $_POST['subscription'];

Comment: @ashutosh No. You misunderstood me. You can only retrieve the data in PHP once it has been submitted. I will elaborate in my answer.

Comment: okk.. your last edit, clears my mind. now i got it. Thank you very much for your answer and information!!! :)